# Как подключить функцию из другого каталога в Echo?

Tags: golang, echo

Создал проект со структурой:

```
lolo
--views
----count_private.go
--go.mod
--go.sum
--logs.log
--main.go
```

Код в `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "lolo/views"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.GET("/f_count_private", views.FCountPrivate)

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

Код в `count_private.go`

```
package views

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func FCountPrivate(c echo.Context) error {
    return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
}
```

При запуске кода через команду `$ go run main.go` выдается ошибка:

```
$ go run main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:11:28: cannot use views.FCountPrivate (value of type func(c "github.com/labstack/echo".Context) error) as type "github.com/labstack/echo/v4".HandlerFunc in argument to e.GET
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обойти ошибку и сделать так, чтобы я мог в `main()` использовать функцию `FCountPrivate(...)` из другого файла?

Comment: Может go run *.go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пакете `views` импортируйте пакет `"github.com/labstack/echo/v4"`.

В `main` вы используете `e.GET` из `github.com/labstack/echo/v4`, а в пакете `views` вы импортируете `"github.com/labstack/echo"`

Для go это разные пакеты, поэтому тип `echo.Context` в определении `FCountPrivate` отличается от типа `Context`, который используется в типе `HandlerFunc` из пакета `github.com/labstack/echo/v4`.